# CSS / HTML - Why aren't my links turning black?

Tags: html, css

```css
  @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300|PT+Sans+Narrow|Poiret+One|Josefin+Sans);
    
    #header {
      background-color: #16a085;
      width: 100%;
      height: 15%;
    }
    
    #mid {
      width: 100%;
      height: 70%;
      background-color: #FFFFD0;
    }
    
    #foot {
      background-color: #16a085;
      width: 100%;
      height: 15%;
    }
    
    .menubar {
      display: inline-block;
      padding-top: 2%;
      font-family: Poiret One;
      font-size: 30px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .menudiv {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 200px;
    }
    
    #invisdiv {
      width: 30%;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
    
    a:link {
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
```

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>beager.xyz</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
    </head>
      <body>
        <div id="header">
           <div id="invisdiv"></div>
          <a href="index.html"><p class="menubar" id="homebutton">Home</p></a>
                           <div class="menudiv"></div>
          <a href="resume"><p class="menubar">Résumé</p></a>
           <div class="menudiv"></div>
          <a href="contact"><p class="menubar">Contact Me</p></a>
        </div>
        
        <div id="mid"></div>
        
        <div id="foot"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I would like to have the three links on top to be black and not blue, I've been trying for ages. It's probably something stupid but I'm still pretty new to HTML and CSS. Thanks.

My code is above for you. My website is going to be just a personal website for me to send to employers. Thanks again.

Comment: note that you don't need the `:link`

Comment: NB: Your HTML is probably better written like this: http://jsbin.com/xuceje/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 3):

Because, when you are testing your code, you have already visited the pages you are linking to.

The `:link` pseudo-class only matches *unvisited* links.

Either remove it, or write another selector that matches `:visited` as well.

Answer (score 2):

The links are black when testing in JSFiddle. But yeah, you could remove :link, not required. Just use `a { color: black; }`